# Code debugging error Arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I am facing two errors for the below program:

1. On serial monitor it is not printing IN `main()`.
2. When enter `lcd_call()` function. If any key being pressed it goes to next case. As per program it should stay in same window but it is going back to case 1.

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("In main");
  lcd_call();
}

void lcd_call()
{
  int menuOption=0;
  int button;
  do
  {
    switch(menuOption)
    {
    case 0:
      Serial.println("set+date:");
      Display_Date_Time(); 
      timedBeep(shortBeep,1);
      break;
    case 1:
      Serial.println("DISPLAY:");
      lcdClear();
      lcd.print("DISPLAY MENU"); 
      timedBeep(shortBeep,1);   
      break;
    case 2:
      Serial.println("SET MENU:");
      lcdClear();
      lcd.print("SET MENU"); 
      timedBeep(shortBeep,1);   
      break;
    }
    button=read_LCD_buttons();
    if(button==btnRIGHT)
    {
      menuOption=menuOption+1;
      if(menuOption>2)
      {
        menuOption=0;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      menuOption; 
    }   
  }
  while(menuOption<menuOptions);
}
```

Comment: Is the button debounced?

Comment: NO there is no debounce.I am using delay of 5 ms in order to avoid it

Comment: does it print "set+date" or "DISPLAY" or you see nothing on serial monitor?

Comment: what do you mean by menuOption; at the else statement?

Comment: Need more info. Your code alone is not enough.

Comment: I am not seeing nothing ,When key is pressed only i can see change in screen . that what expecting but, it back to display "set+date". which is not expected. Menuoption means entry condition for changing switch

Comment: @user3378973  Just FYI. There is now a stack dedicated to Arduino http://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: better try to fix the serial monitor issue first.